# Adding multiple annotations in one chart MS Chart

Tags: c#, vb.net, mschart

I want to add two annotations for two different line charts which is having same x value and different y values.

1st annotation with linechart1(Target line chart) should be visible always and the 2nd annotation with linechart2(Task done) can be visible only on the data points.

I have to show the "Target" annotation always and the "Taskdone" annotation should appear once the mouse is on its datapoint. however if the mousemove event triggered 1st annotation(Target) disappears and the 2nd annotation appears.

My sample data is here

```
Month | Target |Task Done | Total Tasks
------|--------|----------|------------
Apr   |  10    |  24.92   |  30
May   |  10    |  14.01   |  35
Jun   |  10    |  18.97   |  40
```

Code used

```
private sub CreateAnnoation()
    Dim pd_annotate As CalloutAnnotation = New CalloutAnnotation()
    pd_annotate.CalloutStyle = CalloutStyle.RoundedRectangle
    pd_annotate.CalloutAnchorCap = LineAnchorCapStyle.Arrow
    pd_annotate.Height = 6
    pd_annotate.AxisX = chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX
    pd_annotate.AxisY = chart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisY
    pd_annotate.SetAnchor(chart1.Series("Target").Points(1))

    pd_annotate.AnchorX = chart1.Series("Target").Points(1).XValue
    pd_annotate.AnchorY = chart1.Series("Target").Points(1).YValues(0)
    pd_annotate.Visible = True
    pd_annotate.Text = "Target : " & chart1.Series("Target").Points(1).YValues(0)
    pd_annotate.BackColor = Color.LightYellow
    pd_annotate.ForeColor = Color.Red
    pd_annotate.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 12, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold)
    pd_annotate.LineWidth = 1
    pd_annotate.LineColor = Color.Black
    pd_annotate.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Solid
    chart1.Annotations.Add(pd_annotate)

    Dim ta As CalloutAnnotation = New CalloutAnnotation
    With ta
        chart1.Annotations.Add(ta)
        AddHandler chart1.MouseMove, AddressOf chart1_MouseMove
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub chart1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles chart1.MouseMove
        Dim result As HitTestResult = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y)
        Dim ta As New CalloutAnnotation

        If result.ChartElementType = ChartElementType.DataPoint Then
            chart1.Series("TaskDone").Points(result.PointIndex).XValue.ToString()

            Dim thisPt As New PointF(CSng(chart1.Series("TaskDone").Points(result.PointIndex).XValue),
                                CSng(chart1.Series("TaskDone").Points(result.PointIndex).YValues(1)))

            With ta
                .AnchorDataPoint = chart1.Series("TaskDone").Points(result.PointIndex)
                '.LineWidth = 1
                '.X = thisPt.X + 1
                '.Y = thisPt.Y + 1
                '.Text = thisPt.ToString
                .CalloutStyle = CalloutStyle.Rectangle
                .CalloutAnchorCap = LineAnchorCapStyle.Arrow
                .Height = 5
                .BackColor = Color.LemonChiffon
                .ForeColor = Color.DarkBlue
                .Text = "Total Task=" & chart1.Series("TaskDone").Points(result.PointIndex).YValues(1)
                .Font = New Font("Calibri", 10, FontStyle.Bold)
                .Visible = True

                chart1.Annotations(0) = ta
                chart1.Invalidate()
            End With
        End If

    End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: _however if the mousemove event triggered_ Show the event code and how you create the annotations!! Didn't simply mix up the two annotations??

Comment: Used code is updated here.

Comment: Well, as you are adding the one that shall stay first it will have an index of `0`. And in your mousemove you are referring to that one. Try chart1.Annotations(1) = ta - But I really would recommend using  class level variables for the annotations with nice names so you can work with them is a better way..

Comment: I used chart1.Annotations(1) = ta which solved the problem.

Many Thanks TaW. I want to mark this as my answer.